# How long are multer saved files available?

Tags: node.js, express, save, disk, multer

Hi I am completely new to everything, so keep that in mind.

I am making my express app save images with [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). In the multer documentation it says that multer is saving the files 'on disk'.

What does that exactly mean? I am hosting my app on heroku. When somebody is uploading an image, will the image get deleted after a while? Or is it forever saved on my app?

Sorry if this is a weird question, but I can't find a clear answer to this. I guess that it's only temporarily saved to the disk of the user, but I'm not sure.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: images saved by multer will be available forever....untill you delete them or overwrite them. It is not specific to some session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) allows files to be either stored to memory or to disk.

If these files are stored in memory (RAM), the contents will be destroyed if the server reboots/is powered down.

If these files are stored to disk, they are stored on the file system. You will have configured disk storage with something like this:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({


destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
```

In this example, files will be stored in the /tmp/my-uploads/ directory on the server, until they are deleted, just like any other file on your file system.

Comment: So when using diskStorage, the images are stored locally for every user, is that right? Or are they stored on the server?

Comment: The images are stored on the server, hosting the website. For example, if I configure multer as follows:
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/files')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype))
  }
});

The SERVER is then storing these files. If user A uploads fileA.txt, and then user B uploads fileB.txt, then the ./public/files directory on the server will contain both fileA.txt and fileB.txt.

Comment: Note: If these files are private to each user, you *must* ensure that this directory is not publicly visible and that there is no way for user A to view user B's files. You may want to consider sub directories (perhaps by user ID) containing files for specific users if this is the case.